# How to shorten path in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am writing a Makefile for C++ project and want to shorten these lines because I notice they share the same pattern:

```
IPATH = /lib/inc
OPATH = /lib/build
SPATH = /lib/src
```

I came up with something like

`{I,O,S}PATH = /lib/{inc,build,src}`

(which seems silly and fail anyway).

Are there any ways for shorten those lines above?

Thank you.

Comment: removing C++ tag because this question has nothing to do with C++ except for that you're tangentially using it in a C++ project.

Answer (score 5):

This will work

```
LIB_DIR = /home/Harry/lib

IPATH = ${LIB_DIR}/inc
OPATH = ${LIB_DIR}/build
SPATH = ${LIB_DIR}/src
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am afraid that I have to type more with this because what I want to do is to take advantage from the same "PATH" in "IPATH", "OPATH" and "SPATH"

Comment: The ideal makefile should be `copy-paste` ready, which this one is ... a short makefile is not necessary *better* ...

Comment: @HarryNguyen The amount of typing should be your least concern. Write your code so that a complete stranger can understand it. For example, don't use a single letter to distinguish between three variables.